# ¿Cómo eliminar las líneas verticales de la cuadrícula?

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

Quería saber si existe algún comando de pyplot que me permita sustituir **grid()** por una cuadrícula de líneas horizontales[image]

Comment: Hola! Si agregas el código que estás haciendo, nos sería más fácil ayudarte. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Así harás mejores preguntas y podrás ser ayudado en tus problemas!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solo deseas líneas horizontales puede usar:

```
ax = plt.axes()        
ax.yaxis.grid()
```